# Linking to My Blog on Menu

Tags: routes, nodes

I am creating a new Drupal website.  I want to create a menu tab that links to the My Blog section.  What URL link do I use for this?

Comment: What exactly is the My Blog section? Is it a view? If so, use the page display URL that you find in the Edit View screen.

Answer (score 1):

Should be just (whatever your drupal directory)/blog, if it's installed in root directory, then it would look like http://www.example.com/blog, if the blog you created is different from the system default one, it would be http://www.example.com/your_blog_machine_name